# AS3 Decompiler. How it works

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decompiler

I was always curious how AS3 decompilers work and how someone was able to make one.
Does anyone know?

//
*Note: I'm not interested in a specific decompiler*

Answer (score 2):

You can learn more about using [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/tree/master), it is a low level Actionscript 3 library to parse, create, modify and publish SWF files.